# How to generate Junit report using Junit Core

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am required to run few JUnit tests, using JUNIT CORE. I am able to accomplish this task, but unable to fetch JUnit report for this run. Can any one please suggest me a way in which this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this really what do you want, link lead you to create report from ant task

http://blog.varunin.com/2010/03/ant-script-for-generating-junit-report.html